# Retrieve attribute before saving on Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm running into a issue that I cannot retrieve the value of an instance before I save it. It is returning the updated value in the `save()` method. Also, I cannot store in `__init__` because it is running too many queries. I want to run the queries only when the user saves that instance

Here are my models simplified:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(Users)
    '''def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Groups, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #store original values
        for field in Groups._meta.get_fields():
            f = field
            if not f.many_to_many:
                setattr(self, '__original_%s' % f.name, getattr(self, f.name))
            else:
                userlist = Users.objects.all().filter(groups__id=self.pk)
                setattr(self, '__original_userlist', set(userlist)) #set() to force lazy query and get original value'''

    #function trying to reproduce __init__
    def store(self):
        for field in Groups._meta.get_fields():
            f = field
            if not f.many_to_many:
                setattr(self, '__original_%s' % f.name, getattr(self, f.name))
            else:
                userlist = Users.objects.all().filter(groups__id=self.pk)
                setattr(self, '__original_userlist', set(userlist)) #set() to force lazy query


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.store()
       print(getattr(self, '__original_userlist')) #return the list with users
       super(Groups, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       print(getattr(self, '__original_userlist')) #return the list with users
```

I'm not sure the best way to approach since I have to make the queries. I'm doing that to compare the old and new value, then I can store the values which are different in a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by querying the instance again before the `super()` call and using that object. It returned the old values for all the fields, but I need to check the m2m field as well and it was showing as `users.None`.

To get the values of the m2m I had to use the m2m_change signal!